# VueJS get v-model value to methods

Tags: vue.js, methods, vuetify.js, carousel, v-model

excuse me, i use vuetify for carousel component and i want set duration carousel per slide

template :

```
<v-carousel cycle :interval="interval" v-model="onSlideChange">
       <v-carousel-item>First Item</v-carousel-item>
       <v-carousel-item>Second Item</v-carousel-item>
       <v-carousel-item>third Item</v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
```

data:

```
data() {
    return {
      interval: 1000,
      onSlideChange: null,
    };
}

getValue(slideNumber) {
    if (slideNumber === 0) {
      this.interval === 500;
    } else if (slideNumber === 1) {
      this.interval === 800;
    } else {
      this.interval === 1000;
    }
},
```

i get value 0, 1, 2 carousel slide from v-model="onSlideChange" if i use this code on template

```
{{ onSlideChange }}
```

question: how i get value from v-model to methods ? i use @input="handleInput($event.target.slideNumber)" but not work if

```
<v-carousel cycle :interval="interval" v-model="onSlideChange" @input="getValue($event.target.slideNumber)">
```

Comment: btw am use vuejs v2

Comment: you can access `onSlideChange` in methods with `this.onSlideChange`

Comment: yeah i am try ```this.onSlideChange = slideNumber;``` and call ```{{this.interval}}``` but not change

Comment: i think ```v-model="onSlideChange"``` and ```@input="getValue($event.target.slideNumber)"``` can't use in 1 tag

Answer (score 1):

Solved by anonim? (i am forgot because he hidden/deleted this comment):

use watch

```
watch: {
    onSlideChange(newVal) {
      if (newVal !== null) this.getValue(newVal);
    },
  },
```

and call methods

```
methods: {
    getValue(slideNumber) {
      if (slideNumber === 1) {
        this.interval = 500;
      } else if (slideNumber === 2) {
        this.interval = 800;
      } else {
        this.interval = 5000;
      }
    },
  },
```

thank you very much Mr. anonim and Mr. Mohsen